# How to send input text value to server in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fetch, httprequest

so I've made this **game with Js-jQuery**, in which the player is walking on a wire and has to dodge birds that fly at him. If he is hit, a sentence expressing an existential dread appears. You win by keeping balance between being hit and dodging the birds. *Here is the game:* https://walkingthewire.altervista.org/

**I'd like to implement this functionality:** when the game is won, the player can type in a sentence that will be added to the pool of sentences appearing during the game, when one gets hit by birds. I guess the process should be like this:

1. The user fills a text input
2. on submit, **the text is sent to the server and saved in a file**
3. when the player is hit, a function **retrieves the file**, picks a random sentence from it and displays it.

Now, I have to say that I don't have a thorough education on Js and HTTP requests, so it's also hard for me to understand solutions that I can find online. My idea was to save the text in a JSON file and then read it every time the game is played. I've tried some code that should do point 1. and 2. but it doesn't work.

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="https://walkingthewire.altervista.org" class="submit" id="form">
<input class="pensieroInput" placeholder="pensiero"> 
<button></button> 
</form>
```

and this is the JS:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form') 
const pensieroInput = document.querySelector('.pensieroInput') 
const url = form.getAttribute('action') 

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const pensiero = pensieroInput.value
  const data = {pensiero: pensiero}

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    })
})
```

When the form is submitted, the **console prints this error**: *Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0*. I don't know if it's just a silly fault or the way I'm facing the problem is altogether wrong.

This game was built in a Wordpress environment but uses nothing of Wordpress (I don't know php). I've also copied the game to another domain (https://www.margheritamagatti.it/wtw/) where it's just pure HTML/css/Js and I have the same error.

If anyone can suggest me another solution or knows how to fix this... I've been thinking about this problem for almost an year so you'll save me!

Thank you so much